# Jacobian of primary invariants

Tags: invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and consider $R=K[V]^G$ be the invariant ring of the group G over the field K of char 0. Let $f_1,\ldots f_n$ be a set of primary invariants. Is there a nice geometric characterization of the points where the Jacobian of these polynomials vanishes? For finite reflection groups, this is the reflection hyperplane arrangement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points of constant rank of $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ essentially are the strata of the stratification into orbit types. See [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/rep-tens.pdf) or [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/alg-tens.pdf) and references therein.

Comment: Thanx for the references!